# Did we adapt to Earth or Earth to us?

Tags: astronomy, earth, planets, biophysics, exoplanets

I often hear that Earth is a unique planet because it has life and it has its own inhabitance. We also see a proper balance between plants and humans and other animals. Why life is not possible on another planet? Often people say because the environment of other planets is so different from the earth and it's hard to find a planet like that. It seems pretty satisfactory, I can not live on Mars or Saturn.

On the other hand, I find little misleading, why we put ourselves on other planets to see if life is possible on other planets? There might be different creatures that are used to different environments. There might be creatures that used to sees $H_2SO_4$.

I have two questions. First Is my thinking is true? And If so what makes life rare on other planets or make the earth so unique?

Comment: Not sure physics is the right place for this question, this is much more an astrobiology question that might belong on astronomy.SE. My quick answer is that (1) some environments but not others allow complex structures like life, and (2) we should be unsurprised to find ourselves in such an environment since we are life. Whether the set in (1) is big (lots of weird biospheres are possible) or small (nearly just Earth) is the hard question!

Answer (score 1):

**This question maybe suited for another SE site, and may also be opinion based too, but I find it interesting and would like to answer.**

I believe you’re thinking is correct. Life started on Earth due to (if you are a theist you may disagree) many different processes occurring simultaneously, such that the first carbon based life forms were introduced. And then due to many other conditions, this life progressed to where it is today. This happened based on our understanding of evolution, and the probability that it actually did happen to begin with is extremely small.

This could be the reason that any life forms do not appear to have occurred on other (even similar earth like) planets, as far as we know. But then again, some say this occurrence is likely and is in fact happening now, but communication with us is unlikely due to the distances and the possible non existence of technology on these other planets.

But I think that you’re thinking is correct and it is possible that life could have evolved on **any** planet. There does not seem to be a reason why this should not be the case.

The biological mechanisms to support such life forms would of course be vastly different to ours, and you are correct in that some of these life forms could use $H_2SO_4$, sulphuric acid, as a chemical needed for biological processes. This chemical is certainly harmful to all earth based biological life.

The probability of finding life on other Earth-type planets,  that could communicate with us, can be calculated using the  [Drake equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drake_equation).

From that article,

*Only one in a million million has the right combination of chemicals, temperature, water, days and nights to support planetary life as we know it. This calculation arrives at the estimated figure of 100 million worlds where life has been forged by evolution*

Also, the [Habitable Exoplanets Catalog (HEC), and data from the NASA Exoplanet Archive](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_potentially_habitable_exoplanets) have made a list potential habitable planets.

Also, the [Fermi paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi_paradox) states that the lack of evidence for extraterrestrial civilisations and estimates that seem to suggest a high probability, leads to a contradiction. As in this link, the contradiction goes as follows:

*There are billions of stars in the Milky Way similar to the Sun*

*With high probability, some of these stars have Earth-like planets*

*Many of these stars, and hence their planets, are much older than the Sun*

*If the Earth is typical, some may have developed intelligent life long ago*

*Some of these civilizations may have developed interstellar travel, a step humans are investigating now*

*Even at the slow pace of currently envisioned interstellar travel, the Milky Way galaxy could be completely traversed in a few million years*

*And since many of the stars similar to the Sun are billions of years older, the Earth should have already been visited by extraterrestrial civilizations, or at least their probes*

*However, there is no convincing evidence that this has happened*

Answer (score 0):

Our typical criteria for the possible existence of life are based on what we observe for life here on Earth:

- The presence of liquid water.
- The presence of energy sources.
- The presence of biological "fuels" (elements involved in biological processes).
- The accessibility to sufficient energy to uphold biological metabolism.
- (There might be more depending on school).

These are based on our definition of life as for example biological and as having some degree of chemical sophistication etc.

Specifically to the first criterion in the list, liquid water is what we mainly keep an eye out for because water happens to be an exceptionally exceptional solvent. [See NASA's view on that here](https://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/Water:_Molecule_of_Life.html). Such a solvent might be a universal requirement for chemical processes as those we define as life, and all life here on earth [requires moisture to some degree](https://www.quora.com/Can-any-species-live-without-water).

There is a range of distance from our sun within which water remains liquid (not freezing, not boiling). This is called **the habitable zone** or **Goldilock's zone**. (This zone is based on the radiation from the sun, so the actual water conditions will vary depending on atmosphere.) Planets outside this zone are typically deemed lifeless simply because liquid water isn't expected to be found there.

[image]
<sup>Source: [manyworlds.space/tag/habitable-zone](https://manyworlds.space/tag/habitable-zone/)</sup>

With all this being said, keep in mind that this is based on the fact that when we say *life* we mean *life as we know it*. A waterless life form is maybe not impossible in theory. Basically, all we can be sure of is that any life on other planets must be vastly different from our sense of life. Possibly, when we find it one day we will be unsure of whether it even qualifies as life at all. Claiming that life exists on other planets might simply be an issue of definition.